# matchMedia Is not working when using angular universal for serverside rendering

Tags: angular, angular-universal

In normal angular. I do this.

```
export class BasicLayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  private mediaMatcher: MediaQueryList = matchMedia(`(max-width: ${SMALL_WIDTH_BREAKPOINT}px)`);
  @ViewChild(MatSidenav) sidenav: MatSidenav;
  @ViewChildren('sidenav') sidenavs: QueryList<MatSidenav>;

  constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute,
              private _router: Router,
              zone: NgZone) {
    this.mediaMatcher.addListener(mql => zone.run(() => this.mediaMatcher = mql));

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this._router.events.subscribe(() => {
      if (this.isScreenSmall()) {
        if (this.sidenavs.first) {
        this.sidenavs.first.close();
        } 
      }
    });
  }

  isScreenSmall(): boolean {
    return this.mediaMatcher.matches;
  }
}
```

But when I do serverside rendering with angular universal it doesnt work.
I get the error 
ERROR { Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: matchMedia is not defined

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Some variables and functions are only available client-side, not server side, such as `document`, `window` since they are defined by the browser. `matchMedia` likely belongs to this list

You should modify your code to use these variables/functions if you are client side, using the platformId token to identify wether the code being executed is client-side or server-side

https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/README.md#universal-gotchas

Comment: I'm just read it! And they said they provide a **Very Primitive** version of the window object. The "Primitive" version doesnot has the matchMedia function as far as I know. I don't know they are aiming to upgrade that primitive version.